# Teamcity MSBuild publish output directory

Tags: msbuild, teamcity, publish

I am using Teamcity to publish a web app I have created, with targets `Rebuild, ResolveReferences, _WPPCopyWebApplication, Package` and the following command line parameters

```
/p:Configuration=Release;PackageLocation="%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%/Publish"
/p:WebProjectOutputDir=publish
/p:OutDir=publish\bin\
/p:DebugSymbols=false 
/p:DebugType=None
/verbosity:diag
```

The package gets created correctly, but ends up in a folder that is

`%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%/Publish/Archive/Content/C_C/%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%/Web/obj/Release/Package/PackageTmp`

where I would expect it to be created in either

`%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%/Publish`

or

`%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%/Publish/Web`

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 7):

Add `/p:PackageLocation="%system.teamcity.build.workingDir%/Publish/Web"` to your parameters for the build step.